# Nested for loop for column data processing in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, for-loop, nested

I have 100 column xlsx file with size (4097,100). I need to read first column and do some processing and this results in four row variables (1,4097 each) for the first column data only. Further, I need to process each of these four row variables to obtain its statistical parameters such as min, max, mean, SD, var in MATLAB. How to do it with nested for loop?
I appreciate your help. The sample MATLAB code that I am trying is where I have considered only two columns A1 and A2:

```
A = xlsread('S.xlsx');
num_rows = size(A,1);
num_cols = size(A,2);
A1 = A (:,1);
A2 = A (:,2);
B = {A1,A2};
for i = 1:2
for j = 1:4
IMF = emd(B{i},'STOP',[0.1,0.5,0.05],'MAXITERATIONS',100);
I1 = IMF (1,:);
I2 = IMF (2,:);
I3 = IMF  (3,:);
I4 = IMF (4,:);
imf = {I1, I2, I3, I4};
m1(j) = mean(imf{j});
m2(j) = min(imf{j});
m3(j) = max(imf{j});
m4(j) = std(imf{j});
m5(j) = var(imf{j});
end
end
```

Another variation in the code I tried is:

```
A = xlsread('S.xlsx');
num_rows = size(A,1);
num_cols = size(A,2);
A1 = A (:,1);
A2 = A (:,2);
B = {A1,A2};
for i = 1:2
IMF = emd(B{i},'STOP',[0.1,0.5,0.05],'MAXITERATIONS',100);
I1 = IMF (1,:);
I2 = IMF (2,:);
I3 = IMF  (3,:);
I4 = IMF (4,:);
imf = {I1, I2, I3, I4};
for j = 1:4
m1(j) = mean(imf{j});
m2(j) = min(imf{j});
m3(j) = max(imf{j});
m4(j) = std(imf{j});
m5(j) = var(imf{j});
end
end
```

But no success. I am getting the stats values only for the first column i.e. four values for I1, I2, I3 and I4. The second column A2 is not being processed.

Comment: _I need to read first column and do some processing and this results in four row variables (1,4097 each) for the first column data only_    what is the meaning of **four row variables** in this line?

Comment: Dear Muhammad, the processing of first column results in four separate variables, each with one row and 4097 columns. Sorry for confusion. I am close to the final answer, as suggested by m7913d, there is a problem of overwriting. This is solved. But now I need to work on making the code faster. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if it solved your problem or write an answer yourself, which may be useful for other people.

Comment: Why are you posting questions, receive answers and then delete the questions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you overwrite your results. You can always run your code step by step using the [Matlab debugger](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to check what exactly happens.

```
A = xlsread('S.xlsx');
m1 = zeros(2, 4);
m2 = zeros(2, 4);
m3 = zeros(2, 4);
m4 = zeros(2, 4);
m5 = zeros(2, 4);
for i = 1:2
    IMF = emd(A(:, 1),'STOP',[0.1,0.5,0.05],'MAXITERATIONS',100);
    m1(i, :) = mean(IMF, 2);
    m2(i, :) = min(IMF, [], 2);
    m3(i, :) = max(IMF, [], 2);
    m4(i, :) = std(IMF, 0, 2);
    m5(i, :) = var(IMF, 0, 2);
end
```

Note that I removed some temporary variables, avoided the nested loop and preallocated the variables outside the loop. This may decrease the execution time.